# Encapsulamento confuso em c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Eu estava criando um modelo que em seu `construtor` eu definido o atributo `Nome`. entretanto esse atributo irá possuir apenas o `get`, como diferente do `java` o c# possui o recurso para `getters and setters` pensei em simplesmente declarar o `get`, pois já que `Nome` seria setado dentro da `classe` acredito eu que não haveria restrição, mas me surpreendi quando o `VS` acusou `erro`. falando que o atributo `Nome` é `somente leitura`. mas estou setando ele dentro da minha `própria classe`, desculpem minha ignorância mas porque essa restrição? isso faz sentido ? acredito eu que se isso não funciona vou ter que trabalhar como no java atributto `privado` e `getter` publico, certo ?

```
public class Pessoa
{
      public String Nome { get; }    
      public Pessoa(String nome) {
          Nome = nome;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para evitar que o set seja publico também, você pode fazer assim:

```
public class Pessoa
{
      public String Nome {private set; get; }    
      public Pessoa(String nome) {
          Nome = nome;
      }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Rodrigo Santos.

Answer (score 8):

Vinicius é algo simples o que está acontecendo... 
Não está todo errado a sua lógica, porém o que acontece no seu caso, é que você fez a propriedade apenas com o `get`

Existem algumas maneiras de trabalhar assim, mas atenha-se que em algum momento elas devem permitir o SET

Exemplo do Rodrigo Santos

```
    public class Pessoa
    { 
          public String Nome {private set; get; }    
          public Pessoa(String nome) {
               Nome = nome;
          }
    }
```

Outra maneira:

```
    public class Pessoa
    {
           private string _nome;
           public String Nome { get { return _nome; } }    
           public Pessoa(String nome) {
                _nome = nome;
           }
    }
```

Como você declarou a sua property sem o SET ou um Field, o compilador vai acusar um erro, pois ela vai gerar o código que você digitou e verá que não tem uma propriedade SET, ai não poderá setar o valor e gerará uma exception